# How to add Latex-Style Terms in html tables in matlab publish reports

Tags: html, matlab, latex

I've lately started to create documentation for some Matlab/Simulink and Stateflow codes/models etc after around ten years Matlab abstinence.

When documenting a Matlab (R2017b) code I can use the built-in function publish to create a documentation which uses both html and latex format. However for Simulink models it seems I'll need to limit myself on html documentation as long as I don't want to use the Report-Toolbox (for which I have no licence).

Now I want to create tables (with html Markup) where I'd like to insert latex equations or terms, but it seems I'll need a html to latex converter for that (See screenshot [image: of print in html-format]: Equation is created in latex format, the table in html, then there should appear a table in latex-format including the same terms below the text).

When I try it -in publish- by using latex tables as described in the latex Matlab help for [LaTEX Markup](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btga6k2-3):

```
%% LaTeX Markup Example  
% <latex>
% \begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
% \hline $n$&$n!$\\ 
% \hline 1&1\\ 2&2\\ 3&6\\ 
% \hline 
% \end{tabular} 
% </latex>
%
```

the given table actually doesn't appear (or doesn't work) in the created html-file. I suppose it would appear if I choose to print the file in tex-format (I couldn't so far create a pdf-file from the created tex-file ->ERROR), but that doesn't seem satisfactory. I must admit my latex skills are very basic and due  to the fact that my documentation wouldn't be restricted to m-files I would rather look for a html-option.

I'd like to know if there's a way to solve this issue with or (preferably) without external software. If possible with a short instruction.

Comment: Reading the docs you cite I *think* that you can only HTML-publish basic equations (using `$` or `$$`), and not full fledged LaTeX markdown. The LaTeX publishing does, well, exactly that: publish LaTeX code, which should be compiled using a TeX editor. My hunch is that that's why your table doesn't show in your HTML, as the HTML thingy of MATLAB (and usually outside MATLAB as well) doesn't come with a LaTeX compiler. Citing the docs: *If you publish the file to LaTeX, then the Editor opens a new .tex file containing the LaTeX markup.*

Comment: @Adriaan Yeah that was also my conclusion. But it would be stylistically awful to have a latex equation and the terms described in html therefore I hope for a html-solution for that issue.

Comment: Then use a TeX editor to do your documentation. "Use the right tool for the right job". Whilst MATLAB is capable of much (and probably this as well), it's simply easier to just open a TeX editor and use that for documentation.

Comment: @Adriaan that's what I try to avoid, my html-skills are far better, and when documenting Simulink models I won't be able to use TEX for documentation.

Comment: Then I suggest you start learning LaTeX, as documenting anything containing equations will be easier in there than in HTML afaik. Besides, why can't you use TeX for documentation of simulink models? Just make screenshots and paste them in your favourite TeX editor. This question sounds like "I want to use LaTeX but not learn it, as I prefer HTML", which is rather weird.

Comment: @Adriaan well my question is rather why do inline latex equation work while tables don't. The fact that inline latex in html won't work seems to me acceptable.